How to display solid color as fadingEdge top in ScrollView Android
I am trying to create a custom ScrollView in Android where I want to display a solid color (#232325) at the top as a fading edge. The goal is to have the top fading edge behave like a solid color block rather than a gradient.
my extended class for scrollView as follows:
class TopFadeEdgeScrollView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : ScrollView(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    private val fadeHeight = 100 // Height for the top fading effect
    private val solidColor = Color.parseColor("#232325") // Solid color

    private val paint = Paint().apply {
        color = solidColor
        style = Paint.Style.FILL
    }

    init {
        setFadingEdgeLength(fadeHeight)
    }



    override fun getBottomFadingEdgeStrength(): Float {
        return 0.0f // Disable bottom fading edge
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        // Draw solid color at the top
        canvas.drawRect(0f, 0f, width.toFloat(), fadeHeight.toFloat(), paint)
    }
}

myFargment.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.example.anymax_v1.TopFadeEdgeScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:fadingEdgeLength="140dp"
    android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/home_pinned_episode_recycle" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1500dp"
            android:background="@color/purplemain"
            android:text="@string/app_name" />

    </LinearLayout>
</com.example.anymax_v1.TopFadeEdgeScrollView>

Expected result:
1/ A solid color (#232325) appearing as a top fading edge, covering a specific height (e.g., 140dp).
2/ No gradient, no transparency—just a solid block of color.
3/ The bottom fading edge should be fully disabled.
Actual result:
I'm still seeing a faint gradient or alpha blending effect at the top, even though I’ve set the same start and end colors for the LinearGradient.
It seems the gradient or transparency is still being applied despite using a solid color.
How can I create a top fading edge with a solid color and completely disable the bottom fading edge? What could be causing the unwanted gradient effect?

Maybe set  android:requiresFadingEdge="none" will help.

I don't know how customized you want your implementation, but the ScrollViews themselves have fades.

Anyway, if you want to achieve it with a more manual approach, you could try something like this by adding a gradient to the shader.
paint.shader = LinearGradient(
            0f, 0f, 0f, fadeHeight,
            ContextCompat.getColor(context, android.R.color.black),
            ContextCompat.getColor(context, android.R.color.transparent),
            Shader.TileMode.CLAMP
        )

